# Does using setRetainIstance(true) and transition between fragments can result in memory leaks?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, shared-element-transition

Is it possible at all to use those 2 mechanisms together? If so, how should I do it to avoid memory leaks? Especially how should I take care of shared elements?